# Will a Visual Studio 2015 database project by default drop stored procedures not in project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-project

Let's say that someone - for some reason - manually creates a SP in the database (and does *not* add it to the database project). If we now run the publish wizard of the database project, will the manually added SP be dropped or not?

Comment: By default, no. But I'd check the actual settings / the generated script first to be sure the setting hasn't changed.

Comment: @TZHX Put that comment as an answer and i'll accept it. Please also provide a source of information if you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, it won't be dropped.

If you publish from the *database project* (as in, right click and publish), then by default it is off: [An Overview of Database Project Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833291(v=vs.100).aspx) (I know this is from 2010, but the defaults haven't changed)

The project setting is called: "DROP Objects in target but not in project", and found on the "Debug" tab. When you right-click, publish you should get the standard publish profile dialog that gives you the "Advanced" button with below described options.

In the publish profile, it is called "Drop objects in target but not in source." It is unchecked by default, and can be changed from going to the "Drop" tab of "Advanced Publish Settings".

Here you get additional options to not drop specific object types.

[image]

I would recommend checking this value, rather than relying on the defaults (which can be verified by creating a new publish profile).

<sub>As always, when dealing with production databases, I'd recommend checking the script before allowing it to run. These machines, man, you can't trust them.</sub>